# Puppeteer: opening page, extracting data, closing and continuing

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm scraping a .NET site and one common operation I need to perform is:

1. set form, submit
2. open page with result data
3. extract values form a table
4. return to form, repeat with different form paramaters

I can see how to open a page, wait for it via `browser.on('targetcreated')`, then extract the data, however how do I cause the previous code to wait for the tab to close before submitting the form with the next set of parameters? The result page must be parsed before the next operation is submitted as it share's the same URL.

This is perhaps a more general JS question.

This is my current code which checks if a page needs to be opened then clicks the link.

```
 async function fetchAnalysis(page, eventBandId, x, y) {
     const ANALYSIS_TIMEOUT = 90000; // 90 seconds
     const xElem = await page.$(SELECTORS.event_band_analysis_x_axis);
     await xElem.type(x[1])
     const yElem = await page.$(SELECTORS.event_band_analysis_y_axis);
     await yElem.type(y[1])
     await page.click(SELECTORS.event_band_analysis_calculate);
     await page.waitForSelector(SELECTORS.spinner, { timeout:ANALYSIS_TIMEOUT, hidden: true });

     // check if grid is presented straightaway
     var dataTableSelector = null;

     if (await page.$(SELECTORS.event_band_immediate_grid) !== null) {
         console.log("Got data immediatly");
         await page.screenshot({ path: './screenshots/Analysis: '+x[1]+' VS '+y[1]+'.png' });
         var dataTableSelector = SELECTORS.event_band_immediate_grid;
     } else {
         console.log("Need to open page for data");
         // await page.waitForSelector(SELECTORS.event_band_open_data_page);
         await page.click(SELECTORS.event_band_open_data_page);
         console.log("Clicked");
         return;
     }

     const tableData = await utils.getTableDataAsJson(page, dataTableSelector);
     await db.query('INSERT INTO vs_coding.event_band_result ( event_band_id, x_axis, y_axis, json_data ) VALUES (?,?,?,?)', [ eventBandId, x[1], y[1], JSON.stringify    (tableData) ], function (error, results, fields) {
         if (error) throw error;
     });
     console.log("Saved");
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution to opening a page, grabbing the data and then continuing: don't use the `on.('targetcreated')` event, instead just work with the page in front of you.

```
[..snip..]
            await fetchAnalysis(page, eventBandId, mode.name, x, y);
            resultPage = await browser.newPage();
            await utils.navigate(resultPage, 'analysisViewData.aspx');
            await captureTableData(eventBandId, mode, x, y, resultPage, SELECTORS.event_band_analysis_results_grid);
            await resultPage.close();
```